# TapGesture не определяет image в ScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
 @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

 // --------------- SCROLLVIEW -----------------------

 let imageWidth:CGFloat = 75 // размер изображения 75
 let imageHeight:CGFloat = 75

 let yPosition:CGFloat = 0 // для варианта по вертикали
 var xPosition: CGFloat = 20 // у = 20 при ландскапе...
 var scrollViewContentSize:CGFloat = 0;

 //----------scroll for ------------------------------

 for index in 0 ..< showPicture.count // без шатла...
 {
 var pictureImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: showPicture[index])! 
// без шатла

 var pictureImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
 pictureImageView.image = pictureImage
 pictureImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit   //Fit
 pictureImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
 pictureImageView.frame.size.height  = imageHeight
 pictureImageView.center = self.view.center
 pictureImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition // для варианта по горизонтали
 pictureImageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition // для варианта по вертикали

 scrollView?.addSubview(pictureImageView) // показ на экране

 // self.view.addSubview(scrollView) // работает без этого
 let spacer:CGFloat = 20
 xPosition+=imageWidth + spacer // для варианта по горизонтали
 // yPosition+=imageHeight + spacer // для варианта по вертикали

 scrollViewContentSize += imageWidth + spacer // для варианта по горизонтали
 // scrollViewContentSize += imageHeight + spacer // для варианта по вертикали

 scrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSize, height: imageHeight)
 //was        
 pictureScrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSize, height: imageHeight)

 scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
 scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 pictureImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 //       pictureScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

 }  //скобка закрытия for

 // ------------------------- tapGestureRecognizer start -------------------

 var pictureScrollView/*: UIImageView!*/ = scrollView

 let doubleTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer! = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doubleTapped(_:)))

 doubleTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
 doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
 //doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
 //self.showPicture.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
 self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer) // без этого тап не работает
 doubleTapGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
 doubleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

 //self.view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer) // var
 //pictureImageView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)

 //     self.scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // ==??? работает без этого...

 // -------------------- tapGesture_finish ---------------------------------------

 } // скобка func runMeScroll...

 //---------------- func doubleTapped -------------------------------------------

 func doubleTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer!/* = nil*/) {

 //    func doubleTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
 //was =  gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer or AnyObject

       print("UITap = OK"); // вывод на печать происходит, Тар работает...

       var imageViewScroll = sender!.view as? UIImageView // = ???
       var imageView: UIImage? = self.imageViewScroll?.image

       print(imageView); // дает вывод на печать = nil

       if imageView == nil {
          print("imageView не ОПРЕДЕЛЕН");
       else {
          print("imageView  ОПРЕДЕЛЕН"};
       } // bracket if

 } // bracket func doubleTapped
```

Как можно получить imageView в scrollView?

Comment: @VAndrJ не сталкивались с этим = ?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае в момент определения `UIImageView` и настройки его, необходимо создать жест и добавить его для `UIImageView` и только потом положить `UIImageView` на `UIScrollView`.

**UPD:**

Логика должна быть приблизительно такая.

```
private func configureScrollView() {
   for index in 0..< array.count {

      var image = UIImage(named: imageName)
      var imageView = UIImageView()

      let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
      imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
      scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
   }
}

@objc private func tapAction() {
      print("tap Action")
}
```

Comment: как это выглядит физически = ? @Vitaly

Comment: попробую встроить...спс... @Vitaly

Comment: перебросил }bracket for в нужное место и пошло со старыми кодами...спс...@Vitaly

Answer (score 0):

Есть предположение, что вы неправильно идете по дереву view. Жест добавляете на scroll view, значит в sender.view - это UIScrollView, а уже у этого view нужно обращаться к subviews и выцеплять UIImageView. (Но возможно я и ошибаюсь)